# BASH - Reading Multiple Lines from Text File

Tags: bash, text, concatenation

i am trying to read a text file, say file.txt and it contains multiple lines.

say the output of `file.txt` is

```
$ cat file.txt
this is line 1

this is line 2

this is line 3
```

I want to store the entire output as a variable say, `$text`.
When the variable `$text` is echoed, the expected output is:

```
this is line 1 this is line 2 this is line 3
```

my code is as follows

```
while read line
do
    test="${LINE}"
done < file.txt

echo $test
```

the output i get is always only the last line. Is there a way to concatenate the multiple lines in file.txt as one long string?

Comment: the solutions provided does not work so far.


Maybe I should explain what I want more clearly...

I have a file called file.txt for example. The file contains a sentence "this is line 1" "this is line 2" "this is line 3". That is, 3 lines in a text file. And i want to save those lines as one string concatenated together in a bash variable, such as $text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can translate the `\n`(newline) to (space):

```
$ text=$(tr '\n' ' ' <file.txt)
$ echo $text
this is line 1 this is line 2 this is line 3
```

If lines ends with `\r\n`, you can do this:

```
$ text=$(tr -d '\r' <file.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Comment: [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter) - You can use `tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt`.

Comment: Your file contains `\r`. You can remove those `\r`s by command: `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, may i know how to concat the commands together?

Comment: text=$(tr -d '\r' <file.txt | tr '\n' ' ')

genius! that worked!

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
line=$(< file.txt)
line=${line//$'\n'/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test=$(cat file.txt | xargs)
echo $test
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the content of the next line to your variable:

```
while read line
do
    test="${test} ${LINE}"
done < file.txt

echo $test
```

Resp. even simpler you could simply read the full file at once into the variable:

```
test=$(cat file.txt)
```

resp.

```
test=$(tr "\n" " " < file.txt)
```

If you would want to keep the newlines it would be as simple as:

```
test=<file.txt
```

Comment: test=$(tr "\n" " " < file.txt) 

that command returns the last line only when i echoed $test

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the simplest method:

```
text=$(echo $(cat FILE))
```

But it doesn't preserve multiple spaces/tabs between words.

Comment: i tried this. same outcome, the echo $text return the last line in the text file. i want everything as one long string.

Comment: You can check with `echo $(echo $(cat file.txt))`

Comment: thats what i did and it returned the last line

Comment: I really don't know why. I've just checked with dash, bash and zsh, everything works.

Comment: thats weird.. im been stuck for hours! it sounds like a simple problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    a=( "${a[@]}" "$line" )
done < file.txt

echo -n "${a[@]}"
```

output:

```
this is line 1  this is line 2  this is line 3
```

See e.g. [tldp section on arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

Comment: You can use `a+=($something)` to append to an array. tldp articles are generally not very good. You can also use `mapfile -t` to accomplish this (bash v4) or simply `read -d '' -ra array < file.txt` in bash v3